# Creating Dummies in Pandas with conditional statement

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

In my dataset, I want to create dummy variables for the variable "eps". The condition should be something like this, if the eps of certain company is more than 10 euro, I want to assign 0  otherwise 1 for everything else.

Here's the sample image :

[image]

Comment: I strongly advise you to have a read here about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on stackoverflow. In any case, IIUC you are looking to populate that 'dummies' column with 1's or 0's depending whether the EPS is greater than 10. If that, you can try the following: ```import numpy as np```, and then create that column ```df['dummies'] = np.where(df['EPS']>10,1,0)```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I'll read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can start by using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to assign a boolean value in a new column :

```py
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df["Dummies"] = np.where(df["Eps"] > 10, 1, 0)
>>> df
    stock_name  Eps Dummies
0   Apple       20  1
1   Tesla       25  1
2   Berkshire   10  0
```

Then we can even use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to get a dummies matrix format :

```py
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, values='Dummies', columns=['stock_name'], aggfunc=np.min)
stock_name   Apple  Berkshire   Tesla
Dummies      1      0           1
```